# Update statement conflicted with foreign key

Tags: c#, sql, database

Here is my tables,i can update ad,soyad and email but when i try to update telefon it conflicts with the foreign key [userFk],i already have foreign key update on cascade so,i can't figure out the issue here.Thanks in advance

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ogrenci] (
[ogrenciNo]  INT           NOT NULL,
[ad]         NVARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
[soyad]      NVARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
[email]      NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[fakulte_no] INT           NOT NULL,
[bolum_ad]   NVARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
[bolum_no]   INT           DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,
[telefon]    NVARCHAR (50) DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ogrenciNo] ASC),
UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([ogrenciNo] ASC),
UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([email] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [bolumFk] FOREIGN KEY ([bolum_no]) REFERENCES [dbo].[bolum] ([bolumNo]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT [fakulteFk1] FOREIGN KEY ([fakulte_no]) REFERENCES [dbo].[fakulte] ([fakulteId]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT [userFk] FOREIGN KEY ([telefon]) REFERENCES [dbo].[loginusers] ([upassword]) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

);

and the second one,

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[loginusers] (
[username]  NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[upassword] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([upassword] ASC)
```

);

and here is the update button,

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (txtOgrenciNo.Text.Length != 0 && txtAd.Text.Length != 0 && txtSoyad.Text.Length != 0 && txtEmail.Text.Length != 0 && txtTelefon.Text.Length != 0)
            {
                string query = "UPDATE ogrenci SET ogrenciNo=@ogrenciNoVal,ad=@adVal,soyad=@soyadVal,email=@emailVal,telefon=@telefonVal WHERE ogrenciNo=@ogrenciNoVal";
                string query1 = "UPDATE loginusers SET username=@emailVal,upassword=@telefonVal WHERE username=@telefonVal";
                using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query1, connection))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ogrenciNoVal", txtOgrenciNo.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adVal", txtAd.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@soyadVal", txtSoyad.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailVal", txtEmail.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telefonVal", txtTelefon.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailVal", txtEmail.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telefonVal", txtTelefon.Text);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
                    gridDoldur();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Öğrenci bilgileri boş girilemez.", "Bilgilendirme", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you have logical error, in your `loginusers` table primarykey is `upassword`, there may be different users with same password, am I right?

Comment: well in loginusers table i made the users phone number is actually the userpassword so since everyone has different phonenumbers , no different users can not have same pass.

Comment: Ok I got it, I will post answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `upassword` column is primarykey in your `loginusers`  table, if you want to update `telefon` on `ogrenci` with `update cascade property`, so you need to remove `,telefon=@telefonVal` code from `update ogrenci` query, like this

```
string query = "UPDATE ogrenci SET ogrenciNo=@ogrenciNoVal,ad=@adVal,soyad=@soyadVal,email=@emailVal WHERE ogrenciNo=@ogrenciNoVal";
```

Your `second query` will update table `ogrenci` too

**WARNING:**
It will not good if some student will think like this - "If my password is my telephone, so lets try login as another student with his/her telephone number as password and do something" :)

**EDIT:**

Your `second query` `where clause` is wrong I think,

```
string query1 = "UPDATE loginusers SET username=@emailVal,upassword=@telefonVal WHERE username=@telefonVal";
```

It should change to this

```
string query1 = "UPDATE loginusers SET username=@emailVal,upassword=@telefonVal WHERE upassword=@oldtelefonVal ";
```

Comment: It will not good if some student will think like this - "If my password is my telephone, so lets try login as another student with his/her telephone number as password and do something"

Comment: it stopped showing the error but still no update on telefon column. @IkramTurgunbaev

Comment: yeah i miswrote that but still , can't update the telefon column :D @IkramTurgunbaev

Comment: string query = "UPDATE ogrenci SET ogrenciNo=@ogrenciNoVal,ad=@adVal,soyad=@soyadVal,email=@emailVal WHERE ogrenciNo=@ogrenciNoVal";
                    string query1 = "UPDATE loginusers SET username=@emailVal,upassword=@telefonVal WHERE username=@emailVal";

Comment: sorry about messy posts im new to this site

Comment: no it's not problem, since `upassword` is **PK** we should use this `column` in `where clause`, do we know `old upassword value` before` update`?

Comment: yes its a datagridview with the inserted values of database and we can see the values , the point is to allow user edit what he wants in the datagrid

Comment: you should use that oldtelephonevalue in where clause, I will edit my post, take a look

Comment: okay i managed to update telefon column now but i can't reupdate it this time :D i can reupdate other one succesfully

Comment: I didn't clealry understand, can you show your second update query now?

Comment: string query1 = "UPDATE loginusers SET username=@emailVal,upassword=@telefonVal WHERE username=@emailVal";    //i update all of them succesfully but if i try to update telefon column a second time it does nothing.No error whatsoever but nothing happens,

Comment: No, your update query is not as I said, change your update like on my post, and you will get solution

Comment: Your second update query will get 3 parameters after changing

Answer (score 0):

To resolve your problem you need to insert your row in loginusers (not update) after that you need to update your table ogrenci , in the end you can suppress your loginusers row .